# Factory pattern for stack allocated objects in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stack, stack-allocation

I'm a beginner c++ programmer and I would like to know whether it is possible to create **stack-allocated objects** with a **factory design pattern** like in this code.

'''

```
class IInterface {
public:
    virtual ~IInterface() = default;
};

class Car : public IInterface
{
public:
    Car()
    {
        std::cout << "Car Created with Value " << this->x << std::endl;
    }
    ~Car()
    {
        std::cout << "Car Destructed" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    size_t x = 6;
};

class Bus : public IInterface
{
public:
    Bus()
    {
        std::cout << "Bus Created with Value " << this->x << std::endl;
    }
    ~Bus()
    {
        std::cout << "Bus Destructed" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    size_t x = 9;
};

IInterface Factory(int random = 0)
{
    if (random == 1)
    {
        Bus b;
        return b;
    }
    Car c;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    IInterface I = Factory(1);
}
```

'''

If this is correct, I would like to know stack object inside the **Factory()** function gets copied to the **main()** function, and am I able to dynamic cast to an appropriate derived cast later to get the data members?

Comment: Something like this would work in Java, but C++ is not Java. More focus on a good textbook, less focus on "design patterns" and the rest of the buzzword bingo. No, it doesn't get copied, and a dynamic cast will reward you with a `nullptr`.

Comment: As you've done it, no.   Firstly, `IInterface` is an abstract (non-instantiable) class, so cannot be returned by value.   If that is addressed, returning objects by value would result in object slicing.   Returning a pointer (or reference) would avoid slicing, but cause undefined behaviour if objects of automatic storage duration are returned (since the function would return a pointer/reference to an object that no longer exists).   That could be addressed if your objects had `static` storage duration - but that imposes other disadvantages.

Comment: This `IInterface` is perfectly instantiable, but that's besides the point...

Comment: @Peter and SamVarshavchik thank you for your comments. If I modify Factory function like this -> IInterface& Factory(int random = 0); and modify the code in the main like this IInterface& I = Factory(1);
Bus& d = dynamic_cast<Bus&>(I); will this work? (if so, Why the stack-allocated object in the Factory function returned by reference to the main function does not get nullified or deallocated once we leave the Factory function?)